# Populate a field with the sum of two fields while content creation

Tags: 7

I have a content type named "ABC". Which has three fields

- `field_half`(widget type list(text)),
- `field_full`(widget type list(text)),
- `field_total`(widget type float).

During content creation I want the `field_total` to be populated with the sum of two fields `field_half` and `field_full`.

E.g.

```
`field_total` = `field_half` + `field_full`
```

How can I do this.

Comment: You can make use of `AHAH` API or just do it with some jQuery tricks. http://drupal.org/node/348475

Answer (score 1):

Sounds liks a job for [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field)

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, **including other fields**, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it.

You should just be able to set the field value literally as in your example (i.e. field = fieldA + fieldB)

Comment: while content creation ,does the computed field is not displayed

Comment: I see - let me expand my answer :)

Comment: I've added an answer to your [other question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49158/why-computed-field-is-not-getting-displayed-while-creating-content/49159#49159).