# Why computed field is not getting displayed while creating content

Tags: 7

I using "computed field" Module. I have installed the 7.x-1.0-beta1 version computed field module. Enabled and save the configuration.

I have created a computed field and just displayed "Hello" in my content type "abc".

**But this "computed field is not getting displayed while content creation.**

Any ideas why this computed field is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following JavaScript to your theme or in a module (so it's added on the page you are working on with the fields):

It's pretty rudimentary, but it works!  You might want to expand it to work on keypresses rather than `.change()` events.

```
Drupal.behaviors.jqFill = {
    attach: function(){
      $('#edit-field-half-und-0-value, #edit-field-full-und-0-value').change(function(){
        half = parseInt($('#edit-field-half-und-0-value').val());
        full = parseInt(+$('#edit-field-full-und-0-value').val());
        total = half + full;

        if(!isNaN(total)){
          $('#edit-field-total-und-0-value').val(total);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

**Note** I got the field names from your other question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49149/populate-a-field-with-the-sum-of-two-fields-while-content-creation).

Comment: Should I disable the computed field module?Do I need to add this code to hook_form_alter in a module?

Comment: I'd be inclined to leave computed field enabled, just in case the JS fails or someone has it disabled.  That way the right value will still be saved.  You can add the JS however you want, although adding it using `#attached` in `hook_form_alter()` is probably a good idea!

Comment: Do I need to add the code to hook_form_alter in a module?

Comment: " You can add the JS however you want, although adding it using #attached in hook_form_alter() is probably a good idea!"

Comment: used the following code:$form['#attached']['js'][] = 
      $('#edit-field_half_baths-und-0-value, #edit-field_full_bat-und-0-value').change(function(){
        half = parseInt($('#edit-field_half_baths-und-0-value').val());
        full = parseInt(+$('#edit-field_full_bat-und-0-value').val());
        total = half + full;

        if(!isNaN(total)){
          $('#edit-field_baths_total-und-0-value').val(total);
        }
      });
     => array('type' => 'inline'); But its not working. Is this the correct way to add javascript. sorry I am not good in drupal.

Comment: Check out the [docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) - they should help!